# Convention - Proper Error Handling Web Api 2 - Json Response

Tags: c#, json, api, error-handling, asp.net-web-api2

Based on WebApi2 project, a controller returns `IHttpActionResult`.

By [definition](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) the controller may return *void*, `IHttpActionResult` or `HttpResponseMessage` or any other type.

All good so far, but what bothers me is that on the framework default implementation `BadRequest()` ([source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/ApiController.cs)) accepts the following parameters:

- **ModelState**

*api payload*: `{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"errorCode":["000001"],"message":["What a bad request"]}}`

- **Message (string)**

*api payload*: `{"Message":"What a bad request!"}`

- ***no parameters***

*api payload*: *Content-Length: 0* - nothing

---

As I'm trying to follow rest api **best practices** on how to return exceptions described on [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors), [regarding to http error codes](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2013/05/15/http_problem) and mainly [the content of the response](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_what_about_errors), **should I end up creating a custom** Response by hand in order to have something like:

Http Code: **400**

Payload:

```
{
    "errorCode" : "00001",
    "message" : "What a bad request!",
    "attributes" : [ "Foo" ],
    "moreInfo" : "http://api/errors/00001"
}
```

*...I wonder what guidelines the api team took to define the BadRequest implementation*.